# Equidistant collectionViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with cells of equal size. I want to make the distances between cells and between the cells and the left and right of the collection view all equal, with 2 cells in each row.

The content of each cell is horizontally centered, so I've tried setting the width of the cells to half the collection view's width:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: eventCollectionView.frame.width/2, height: 111)
}
```

But this produces the following:

[image: pic]

As seen, the two cells are at 1/4 and 3/4th of the width. Instead I want them to be at 1/3 and 2/3 so the space between them and the edges are all equal.

Does anybody know how I'd accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add the snap of how you want display it so that I can guid you properly.

Answer (score 2):

use bellow code

```
fileprivate var defaultspacing: CGFloat = 5

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var size: CGSize = .zero

    let width = (SCREEN_WIDTH - (3 * defaultspacing))/2
    size = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    return size;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.defaultspacing, self.defaultspacing, 0, self.defaultspacing);
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return self.defaultspacing;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return self.defaultspacing;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For that, you have to set section Inset property from storyboard whatever you want from left and right side of the collection view, also set the Min Spacing property from storyboard you want[image]

In my case,  I want 5 px from both the side and 5 px between 2 cell.

and in delegate method write,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
return CGSize(width: (eventCollectionView.frame.width - 15)/2, height: 111)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following method in your class

**You can make changes as per your needs**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat(collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 -10), height: CGFloat(111)) // here 10 is the space of cells
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }

    func  collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                         layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                         minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pictures make a lot of sense. My solution will work in every devices in right format.

**Why?**
Please go through the solution.

**Step 1:**

My base layout is iphone 7 plus and i have calculated for this devices.Calculation is done because i need to support all devices.So i had make some constants like below:

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
var BASE_SCREEN_HEIGHT:CGFloat = 736.0
var SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH = max(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
var ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P = SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH / BASE_SCREEN_HEIGHT

let MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING:CGFloat = 46 //My Default Inter Cell Spacing for iphone 7plus as i have designed in it.
var ITEM_WIDTH:CGFloat  = 138 //for iPhone 7 plus.initial value
var ITEM_HEIGHT:CGFloat = 138 //for iphone 7 plus.initial value
let NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_PORTRAIT:CGFloat = 2
let NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_LANDSCAPE:CGFloat = 5
```

**Step 2:**

Then i had to calculate cellsize according the exact space between cells.

```
func  calculateCellSize(screenWidth:CGFloat , cellItem:CGFloat) {
    ITEM_WIDTH = (screenWidth - MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING * 3 * 
ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P  * (cellItem-1)) / cellItem  - 1// This 1 
has been subtracted from ITEM_WIDTH to remove mantissa
    ITEM_HEIGHT = ITEM_WIDTH
}
```

**Step 3:**

1. For between cell spacing you need to call below method.

   public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
       collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
       minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING * ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P
   }
2. And for Padding(with left margin and right margin) you have to call this method.

   public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
   collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt 
   section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
       return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 
   MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING*ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P, 0, 
   MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING*ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P)
   }
3. Overall i had to call 4 methods.I didn't explain the other two methods may be you will understand.

   So basically whole code is like this.

   [image]
     [image]
     [image]
     [image]

   And my output is

   [image]

Comment: i have added my project in github..
https://github.com/junaid4058/collectionViewWithEqualSpacing